# Let X be distribution over N (the set of non-negative numbers), with mass P(X=i) = a/2^i, what is the value of a?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random

I am struggling with solution for following problem part of course about probabilities random variables, seek your kind help to show how to solve it,

Let $X$ be distribution over $N$ (the set of non-negative numbers), with mass 
$P(X=i) = a/2^i$, what is the value of $a$?

Comment: What have you tried towards solving this question? We don't do problems for nothing.

Comment: I have tried solving it through the Expectation formula E(X) = sum( p(x).X) = sum (a/2^x).x = a. sum(1/2^x).x , then I tried to get to a value of a, but unfortunately couldn't reach final conclusion.

Comment: You are thinking to complicated. What other property for probabilities is usually expressed as a sum, assuming only a countable number of outcomes is possible? And regarding your approch. why do you make the assumption that the expectiation is $a$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a}{2^i}=1$, can you sum the series?